# Почему Selenium не видит поле на странице?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

**Заголовок вопроса:**

Хочу написать бота для скрининга музыки из вк но я не могу ввести текст в поле на странице т.к. Selenium не видит это поле "input"

---

**Код страницы:**

[image: -]

---

**Мой код:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://vk.com")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "VkIdCheckbox__name").click()
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "eltt_close_button").click()


elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "index_email")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("Test")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elem2 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vkc__TextField__input")
elem2.clear()
elem2.send_keys("Test")
elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


time.sleep(30)
driver.close()
```

---

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nurlashka\Desktop\vkLogin\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    elem2 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vkc__TextField__input")
  File "C:\Users\nurlashka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element    
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\nurlashka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\nurlashka\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .vkc__TextField__input
```

Comment: Первый клик идет на некликабельный элемент `
        <span class="VkIdCheckbox__name">Сохранить вход</span>`, зачем?

Comment: Элементов `"eltt_close_button"`  и `vkc__TextField__input` на странице "Добро пожаловать" нет.

Comment: Мне нужно перейти ещё раз на новою страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно было указать ожидания, ниже прикрепляю коррекниый вариант кода, буду рад если отметишь мой коммент как коммент который помог решить проблему

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://vk.com")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "VkIdCheckbox__name").click()
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "eltt_close_button").click()


elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "index_email")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("Test")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "vkc__TextField__input")))
# elem2 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vkc__TextField__input")
elem2.clear()
elem2.send_keys("Test")

elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)


driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в том, что элемент с таким классом не загружен на страницу в момент поиска. Возможно, этот элемент появляется на странице только после какого-то действия пользователя, например, клика по какому-то другому элементу. В этом случае нужно дождаться загрузки элемента с помощью одного из методов ожидания (например, WebDriverWait).